Angular library build failing
I have an Angular 17 project which is acting as a test project so I can build and test components from an Angular library which will get built and used amongst various other projects.
My folder structure is as follows:
node_modules -> @design-system -> assets -> fonts -> Poppins -> woff2
                                  css -> design-system.css  
                                  src -> _variables.scss
                                      -> fonts -> _poppins.scss

projects -> my-lib -> components -> button  
ng-package.json

src  
angular.json  
package.json

design-system/src/_variables.scss

@import './fonts/poppins';
@import './fonts/opensans';

/* Grey shades */
$gray-2: #fafafa !default;
$gray-4: #f5f5f5 !default;
$gray-8: #ebebeb !default;
$gray-10: #e6e6e6 !default;
$gray-20: #cccccc !default;
$gray-30: #b3b3b3 !default;
$gray-40: #999999 !default;
$gray-70: #4d4d4d !default;
$gray-90: #1a1a1a !default;

design-system/src/fonts/poppins.scss


@font-face {
   font-display: swap;
   font-family: 'Poppins';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 100;
   src: url("../assets/fonts/Poppins/woff2/Poppins-100-normal-latin-ext.woff2") format('woff2'), url("../assets/fonts/Poppins/ttf/Poppins-100-normal.ttf") format('ttf');
   unicode-range: U+0100-02AF, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+1E00-1E9F, U+1EF2-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20C0, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

@font-face {
   font-display: swap;
   font-family: 'Poppins';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: 200;
   src: url("../assets/fonts/Poppins/woff2/Poppins-200-normal-latin-ext.woff2") format('woff2'), url("../assets/fonts/Poppins/ttf/Poppins-200-normal.ttf") format('ttf');
   unicode-range: U+0100-02AF, U+0304, U+0308, U+0329, U+1E00-1E9F, U+1EF2-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20C0, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

button.scss


@use "@design-system/src/variables" as v;

h2 {
  color: v.$gray-70;
}

and then run ng build my-lib, I get the following error:
✖ Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
Build failed with 71 errors:
<stdin>:8:11: ERROR: [plugin: angular-css-resource] Could not resolve "../assets/fonts/Poppins/woff2/Poppins-100-normal-latin-ext.woff2"
The error is relating to an import inside the variables.scss which is importing the fonts which are inside the assets folder within the design-system node_module. I can serve the project locally and have access to the variables locally. But ng build is not working, any help is greatly appreciated
If I comment out the import within the component then the library builds as expected, but if I can the import back in then the error returns as the error is within the node_modules not being able to find the correct assets

I feel your url should be src: url("assets/fonts/Poppins/woff2/Poppins-200-normal-latin-ext.woff2") or src: url("./assets/fonts/Poppins/woff2/Poppins-200-normal-latin-ext.woff2"). You should think that Angular create and unique style.css (and put it where the index.html are) and create an folder assets that it's in the dame directory where the index.html are. And the folder structure you have has no importance.

@Eliseo Thank you for your comment, the file path you have described is within the npm package of the design-system, I do not feel I should be editing files of an npm package that I dont have control over.
